# Issue with substrings in an array

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that prints the text between two delimiters.

For example, in the string `"superior sanguine bears"` it returns an array of length 4 that contains `"" "uperior" "anguine bear" ""`.

Below is my code. The issue I'm running into is that I'm getting a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 23 at the line `result[arrayLength] = s.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);`

```
public static String[] explode(String s, char d)
{
    String[] result;
    int stringLength;
    int beginIndex, endIndex;
    beginIndex = 0;
    endIndex = 0;
    int arrayLength = 0;

    stringLength = s.length();//set stringLength equal to length of string s
    result = new String[stringLength];

    for(int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == d)
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                result[arrayLength] = "";
                arrayLength++;
            }
            beginIndex = i+1;
            System.out.println("beginIndex" + beginIndex);
        }


        for(int j = i+1; j < stringLength; j++)
        {
            if((s.charAt(j) == d) || (j == stringLength-1))
                endIndex = j;

            if(beginIndex == endIndex)
            {
                result[arrayLength] = s.substring(beginIndex);
                arrayLength++;
            }
            else if(endIndex > beginIndex)
            {
                System.out.println(endIndex);
                result[arrayLength] = s.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
                arrayLength++;

            }
        }
    }


    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = "superior sanguine bears";
    char d = 's';
    String[] answer = explode(s, d);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(answer));
}
```

Comment: Evidently `arrayLength` is exceeding `stringLength`. Why haven't you stepped through your code with a debugger to figure out precisely why?

Comment: Since you made your array out of stringLength, it is stringLength long.  However, array indexing is base zero so (stringLength-1) is really the last spot in your array.

Comment: you are incrementing arrayLength in multiple places within the for loop.

Comment: @SachinThapa The error isn't at line 23, it's at the line I included on a separate line after that (and before all of my code)

Comment: @muratgu is that an issue since they're all in separate if or else if statements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
    package code.java.test;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static List<String> explode(String s, char d)
    {
       List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
       int beginIndex =0;
       int endIndex = 0;
       while((endIndex = s.indexOf(d, beginIndex)) != -1){
           ret.add(s.substring(beginIndex, endIndex).trim());
           beginIndex = endIndex+1;
       }
       ret.add(s.substring(beginIndex, s.length()));
       return ret;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "superior sanguine bears";
        char d = 's';
        List<String> answer = explode(s, d);

        System.out.println(answer.toString());
    }
}
```

O/P: **[, uperior, anguine bear, ]**

Answer (score 1):

You are getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, because you are tring to read an index that does not exist. Array index start with 0 and goes till n-1 element.
Just use below code:

```
String string = "superior sanguine bears";
String[] parts = string.split("s", -1);
System.out.println(parts);
```

Should be good enough.
Note: I assume that "s" is your delimiter.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to include in my question that this is for my data structures class and the instructor only wants us to use the charAt, equals, length, and substring methods of the String class. I thought that looked too simple :/

Comment: I have edited the code for the last empty string. **split("c", -1)** is the way to do that. Thanks for pointing that.